# How to create focused ImageButton in Windows Mobile application?

Tags: windows, mobile, focus

In my Windows Mobile 6.0 application, I have an ImageButton [control given by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=039C5D13-2DA5-42C7-9426-B1F298752B4E&displaylang=en).

I want my ImageButton control to have focus border like any standard button. How I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

I want to suggest the answer after some manipulations with code.

The trick is to check whether the control is focused in OnPaint method and draw transparent or black border:

```
gxOff.DrawRectangle(new Pen((this.Focused) ? Color.Black : Color.Transparent), rc);
```

and call Invalidate() in OnGotFocus and OnLostFocus events:

```
protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs 
{
    base.OnGotFocus(e);
    this.Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLostFocus(e);
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

Hope it will help somebody :)